# Changing title In UIWebview as user scrolls

Tags: cocoa-touch, ios, uiwebview, dynamic-text

I am developing an iOS app. How can I know the current section that is being displayed in the UIWebview and change the title of the navigation bar accordingly? The title will be the section which the user is reading. The sections in the html file displayed in the UIWebView are separated by `<h2>` tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is looking for an answer to this, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7864765/android-webview-detecting-the-header-name-as-the-user-scrolls/7864818#7864818) might help. Its basically done using javascript functions.